# Add asmx web service in xamarin.Forms project (.Net standard 2.0)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, asmx, .net-standard-2.0, web-reference

I'm new in the Xamarin world and I want to add ASMX web service to my Xamarin .Net standard project, but the problem is there is no "add web reference" section.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, Xamarin.forms, .NET standard 2.0.

Any ideas how can I add the asmx web service to the project ?